# What is the significance of modulus sign here

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Let $f(x)$ be a periodic function with period $p$. Then
$$f(x+p)=f(x)$$
Let, $$g(x)=f(ax+b)+c$$
Now it's mentioned in my book that $g$ is also a periodic function with a period of $\frac{p}{|a|}$.

**My questions:-**

$(1)$ Why does period have $|a|$ in it's denomination and why not $a$ simply?

**My understanding:-**
I am saying that it should be $a$ because,
$$g(x+\frac{p}{a})=f(ax+p+b)+c$$
Since $f$ is periodic and have a period of $p$ then,
$$g(x+\frac{p}{a})=g(x)$$
And hence $g$ has a period of $\frac{p}{a}$.

Then why is that modulus sign ?

Comment: Consistent with the answer of Doge Chan, it is presumed that $p > 0$, since the period of the first function was expressed as $p$.  Therefore $~\displaystyle \frac{p}{|a|}~ : ~a \neq 0~$ is also guaranteed to be a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

The Period of a real valued function is a positive value by definition. So $|a|$ is written instead of $a$ to guarantee that you calculate a positive number for $p/|a|$.